# Postgres: Retrieve records Sequentially at 5 seconds interval

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a `postgres` database table with nearly 700k records. I would want to have a python script that fetches the records one-by-one at 5seconds interval until the last record.

How do I go about it?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  For instance, do you mean 5 seconds since the last record?  Or fixed 5-second intervals?

Comment: Do you edit database between fetches? You can just iterate over `cursor.execute` and `sleep` in a loop

Comment: I mean going through the records, in an interval of 5secs between the next fetch. Database not edited, read-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need anything more than that?

```
from time import sleep

import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table")

for record in cur:
    # process record
    sleep(5)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: the whole goal is to read through the records and have the values  sent over http in json format.

Comment: Can you please suggest some guides here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737528/python-retrieving-postgresql-query-results-as-formatted-json-values